# Grails - Ionic - AngularJS - Is it a good idea to work in this Env.?

Tags: angularjs, grails, spring-security, ionic-framework

I want to create an application using **Ionic** and AngularJS and Grails?

Also, I want to use Grails Spring Security Core plugin for login or registrations procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Although, Stack Overflow is not the correct site to ask this type of questions which simply needs suggestions and other's opinions.

Well, we are here to help. You can try other StackExchange sites like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Grails + Ionic + AngularJS is a perfect combination of frameworks to build a fully functional and elegant mobile application for all platform. We've build various mobile applications using these three technologies and they work awesome.

Since Grails fully support the concept of rest API for JSON and AJAX based calls, it is absolutely possible to use it along with AngularJS. AngularJS doesn't care about the server-side technology you are using as long as your server side code can communicate over JSON data.

Ionic is just a beautiful front-end SDK which works on the top of AngularJS and provides various utilities to develop a hybrid user-friendly mobile APP.

So you can easily use these 3 technologies and get your mobile app ready in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic doesn't care about what you use as a server stack. As long as you create a service which has well defined interfaces (REST?), you should be fine.

I for example use PHP (yeah, I know, shocking, right?) Slim framework + Postgres database as my backend.

Comment: I have used php till now, I wanted to check how does it work with Grails and Security plugin. Finding it hard to do in Grails as Grails documentation is not straight forward for me at least.